# How to load a properties file in a java servlet to set a ldap connection variable ?

Tags: java, servlets, properties

In my java web app I have the following DAO constructor.

```
public DAO() throws IOException {

    env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:1389");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=Directory Manager");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "secret");
}
```

I would like to set the env variable loading the following config.properties file:

```
INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
PROVIDER_URL=ldap://localhost:1389
SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION=simple
SECURITY_PRINCIPAL=cn=Directory Manager
SECURITY_CREDENTIALS=secret
```

I load the file with the following code:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
    props.load(in);
    in.close();
```

Now, I tried to set the env variable but it doesn't work:

```
    env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, System.getProperty("INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY"));
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, System.getProperty("PROVIDER_URL"));
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, System.getProperty("SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION"));
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, System.getProperty("SECURITY_PRINCIPAL"));
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, System.getProperty("SECURITY_CREDENTIALS"));
```

Comment: what is the exception? is your `config.properties` file not @ root context path?

Answer (score 1):

You are loading the properties from file into the `props` variable, so you have to use this `props` variable instead of system properties. I.e.

```
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, props.getProperty("INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY"));
// etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a System.getProperty(). You should do:

props.getProperty()

Maybe create a configuration class that loads and maintains your Property object

Answer (score 0):

ok. thank you.
The following code works:

```
public DAO() throws IOException {


    Properties props = new Properties();
    InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
    props.load(in);

    env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, props.getProperty("PROVIDER_URL"));
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, props.getProperty("SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION"));
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, props.getProperty("SECURITY_PRINCIPAL"));
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, props.getProperty("SECURITY_CREDENTIALS"));

}
```